# On clicking on a container it pops up an error that no material widget was found to the child widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I want to open an overlay on clicking on the container '// this container is clicked' and on the click the function showTeacherDetails is called '//this fuction'

```
import 'package:educewebsite/SizeConfig.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class TeachersScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TeachersScreenState createState() => _TeachersScreenState();
}

class _TeachersScreenState extends State<TeachersScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 92,
      width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 80,
      color: Color(0xFFF4F4F4),
      padding:
          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 1),
      child:
          Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 1,
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 1,
          ),
          child: ListTile(
              dense: false,
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.person,
                size: 40,
              ),
              title: Text(
                'Teacher',
                style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                    textStyle:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              )),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              // function to add new teacher
            },
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 2),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 8,
              width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 16,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.lightBlue,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              ),
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.person_add,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                title: Text(
                  'New Teacher',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 75,
          width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 78,
          child: GridView.count(
            childAspectRatio: 5 / 3,
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            children: [
              GestureDetector(                            // this container is clicked
                onTap: () {
                  showTeacherDetails(context);
                },
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      color: Colors.white),
                  child: Text('1'),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5), color: Colors.blue),
                child: Text('2'),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5), color: Colors.blue),
                child: Text('3'),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5), color: Colors.blue),
                child: Text('4'),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5), color: Colors.blue),
                child: Text('5'),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5), color: Colors.blue),
                child: Text('5'),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5), color: Colors.blue),
                child: Text('6'),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5), color: Colors.blue),
                child: Text('7'),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5), color: Colors.blue),
                child: Text('8'),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5), color: Colors.blue),
                child: Text('9'),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5), color: Colors.blue),
                child: Text('10'),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5), color: Colors.blue),
                child: Text('11'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
// function called
  showTeacherDetails(BuildContext context) {
    OverlayState overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
    OverlayEntry overlayEntry;
    overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
        builder: (context) => Positioned(
            width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 25,
            height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 92,
            top: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 8,
            left: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 75,
            child: Container(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 0.5,
                    horizontal: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 1),
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Center(
                  child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.close,
                        size: 40,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () => overlayEntry.remove(),),
                ))));
    overlayState.insert(overlayEntry);
    }
  }
```

this is my code and on clicking to the container it throws an error as:

```
The following assertion was thrown building IconButton(Icon, padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0), dirty):
No Material widget found.
IconButton widgets require a Material widget ancestor.
In material design, most widgets are conceptually "printed" on a sheet of material. In Flutter's
material library, that material is represented by the Material widget. It is the Material widget
that renders ink splashes, for instance. Because of this, many material library widgets require that
there be a Material widget in the tree above them.
To introduce a Material widget, you can either directly include one, or use a widget that contains
Material itself, such as a Card, Dialog, Drawer, or Scaffold.
The specific widget that could not find a Material ancestor was:
  IconButton
The ancestors of this widget were:
  ...
  Center
  Align
  Padding
  ColoredBox
  Container
  ...

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  IconButton
```

I haved tried wrapping the IconButton in container, row, center and all other possible widgets.

Comment: Wrap your top most `Container() ` widget with a `Scaffold()` widget or a `Material()` widget

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
return Scaffold(
   body: SafeArea(
child: Column(
children: [
Container(),
...
...
]
)
)
);
```